# JSON and ASP.Net MVC Controller is not binding the properties of the list of objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, data-binding

I am making an AJAX call with jQuery:

```
        var topic = new Array();

        $('.container-topico').each(function (i) {
            topic.push(
            {
                "TopicsModel":
            {
                begins: $(this).find('.HoursStart').val(),
                ends: $(this).find('.HoursEnd').val(),
                texts: $(this).find('.input-topic').val()
            }
            }
                );
        });

        var data = JSON.stringify({
            videoId: '<%=Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]%>',
            topics: topic
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '<%= Url.Action("SubmitTopics") %>',
            traditional: true,
            data:
            data
        ,

            beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                $(data).each(function () {
                });
            }
        });
```

It is sending the JSON in the format (e.g):

```
{"videoId":"1","topics":


[{"TopicsModel": {"begins":"00:00:33","ends":"00:01:00","texts":"1. Primeiro tema"}},
    {"TopicsModel": {"begins":"00:01:00","ends":"00:01:33","texts":"2. Segundo tema"}},    
    {"TopicsModel": {"begins":"00:01:33","ends":"00:02:00","texts":"3. Terceiro tema"}},
    {"TopicsModel": {"begins":"00:02:00","ends":"00:00:21","texts":"dasdasdsa ada as das s"}},
    {"TopicsModel": {"begins":"0","ends":"0","texts":""}}]}
```

And on the server side it has the Model:

```
 public class TopicsModel
    {
        public string begins;
        public string ends;
        public string texts;
    }
```

and the Controller:

```
public ActionResult SubmitTopics(int videoId, List<TopicsModel> topics)
```

What happen is:

It have the correct number of objects, but **is not binding the properties** of each element, as you can see bellow:

[image: It have the correct number of objects, but is not binding the properties]

Why is it not binding to the properties ?

Comment: Are you definitely using MVC3? I just notice that you are using older style <% %> tags.

Comment: @markpsmith <% %> tags can be used, you can use whatever view engine you're comfortable with. Here, OP has elected to use the older ASPX engine, but the markup is completely valid.

Comment: @MisterJames - that's fine, I only mentioned it because I think that automatic json binding only works in MVC3.  Just ruling it out as a potential issue.

Comment: I am using the ASP.Net MVC version 4, but it was an old project, so I didn't change it to razor view engine yet, but I believe it doesn't affect the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding can't find the `TopicsModel` property in your `TopicsModel` object, so it can't bind the value.

Try this instead :

```
{"videoId":"1","topics":


[{"begins":"00:00:33","ends":"00:01:00","texts":"1. Primeiro tema"},
    {"begins":"00:01:00","ends":"00:01:33","texts":"2. Segundo tema"},    
    {"begins":"00:01:33","ends":"00:02:00","texts":"3. Terceiro tema"},
    {"begins":"00:02:00","ends":"00:00:21","texts":"dasdasdsa ada as das s"},
    {"begins":"0","ends":"0","texts":""}]}
```

The binding should then resume normally.

---

You also have to change your model this way :

```
public class TopicsModel
    {
        public string begins { get; set; }
        public string ends { get; set; }
        public string texts { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I tried this one, and I still have the same error, didn't bind the property.

Comment: I edited the answer, there was also a little something I overlooked. The members of your model actually need to be properties. change it this way : `public string begins { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks @Lostdreamer, it worked like a charm, was the {get; set;} that was missing, strange, I tought it implicitly had get and set.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around, when you use {get;set;} it automatically creates some hidden `members` to match the `properties`. Properties and Members, although they are use in the same way, are 2 different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-naming `List<TopicsModel> topics` in the controller parameter list to `List<TopicsModel> model`